# Works in Access but does not work in SQL Oracle Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This query is pulling all the doctors that has a radio or flouro permit in the column documentname

```
select practitioner_id_numbers.pract_id
      , practitioner_id_numbers.id_number
      , practitioner_id_numbers.expiration_date
      , practitioner_id_numbers.documentname
      , practitioner_id_numbers.historical 
from practitioner_id_numbers 
group by practitioner_id_numbers.pract_id
          , practitioner_id_numbers.id_number
          , practitioner_id_numbers.expiration_date
          , practitioner_id_numbers.documentname
          , practitioner_id_numbers.historical 
 having (((practitioner_id_numbers.documentname) like "Radio*" 
        or (practitioner_id_numbers.documentname) like "Fluoro*") 
        and ((practitioner_id_numbers.historical)=0));
```

Comment: what do you mean by "work" ?

Comment: Assuming you are connected to Oracle, strings are delimited by single quotes not double quotes.  You probably want to use `%` as the wild card rather than `*`.  And there is no boolean data type so I don't know what you want rather than `false`.

Comment: Please don't just paste unformatted code as your question. Please [edit] the question to explain what you're doing, what the expected result was, and what is happening instead.

Comment: it runs on ms access and gives me records... but no records on sql developer?

Comment: Each RDMS maintains its own SQL dialect. Hardly any SQL query is portable between databases.

Comment: Strings in Oracle are delimited by single quotes not double quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Access creates its own version of SQL, which is really annoying because it actually renders the correct SQL to the DBMS itself -- it just doesn't expose it to the end user.  If you want to make this DBMS compatible, you need to take into account that Access created an alias for the table and turned the schema/table separator from a dot to an underscore.

So, depending on whether or not your table name is `practitioner.id_numbers` or `practitioner_id.numbers` the SQL would be different -- assuming it's the latter, the Oracle SQL would be:

```
select practitioner_id.numbers.pract_id
      , practitioner_id.numbers.id_number
      , practitioner_id.numbers.expiration_date
      , practitioner_id.numbers.documentname
      , practitioner_id.numbers.historical 
from practitioner_id.numbers 
group by practitioner_id.numbers.pract_id
          , practitioner_id.numbers.id_number
          , practitioner_id.numbers.expiration_date
          , practitioner_id.numbers.documentname
          , practitioner_id.numbers.historical 
 having (((practitioner_id.numbers.documentname) like 'Radio%'
        or (practitioner_id.numbers.documentname) like 'Fluoro%') 
        and ((practitioner_id.numbers.historical)=0));
```

Note also that In Access a double quote becomes a single for values, and an asterix becomes a percent sign.

To make this same SQL work in Access, you can run it as a pass-thru query, and then your code will be portable from that point forward.  The only drawback is that you can no longer use the designer in Access if you do a pass-thru.

That said, another peril of Access is that it tends to overuse `having` when a `where` would have been preferred.  The following code would be a lot more efficient on the Oracle side, assuming the criteria eliminated a large number of rows:

```
select practitioner_id.numbers.pract_id
      , practitioner_id.numbers.id_number
      , practitioner_id.numbers.expiration_date
      , practitioner_id.numbers.documentname
      , practitioner_id.numbers.historical 
from practitioner_id.numbers 
where (((practitioner_id.numbers.documentname) like 'Radio%' 
        or (practitioner_id.numbers.documentname) like 'Fluoro%') 
        and ((practitioner_id.numbers.historical)=0))
group by practitioner_id.numbers.pract_id
          , practitioner_id.numbers.id_number
          , practitioner_id.numbers.expiration_date
          , practitioner_id.numbers.documentname
          , practitioner_id.numbers.historical
```

And, just for grins, if you want to make it a little more idiomatic, you can add aliases and change the `group by` to a `distinct` (since you don't seem to actually be using grouping functions):

```
select distinct
  pi.pract_id
 , pi.id_number
 , pi.expiration_date
 , pi.documentname
 , pi.historical 
from practitioner_id.numbers as pi
where
  ((pi.documentname like 'Radio%' or
    pi.documentname like 'Fluoro%') and
    pi.historical=0)
```